# How to check same values for the multiple keys in array of json Object?

Tags: ios, json, loops, swift3, calendar

I am working on calendar using `Swift3`. I know it's possible to set same values for different keys.

I have this `NSArray` called `Dictionary` of `JSON` objects:

```
if parsedData["status"] as! Int == 200 {

    if let Streams = parsedData["data"] as! [AnyObject]? {
       for Stream in Streams {
           print(Stream) 
       }



Stream result: {
"-" = 4;
1 = X;
10 = H;
11 = X;
12 = X;
13 = X;
14 = X;
15 = X;
16 = X;
17 = H;
18 = X;
19 = X;
2 = X;
20 = X;
21 = X;
22 = X;
23 = L;
24 = H;
25 = X;
26 = L;
27 = "-";
28 = "-";
29 = "-";
3 = H;
30 = "-";
4 = X;
5 = X;
6 = X;
7 = X;
8 = X;
9 = X;
H = 4;
L = 2;
X = 20;
blank = "";
classid = id;
classname = " (A)";
stdid = 1;
stdnm = "name"; }
```

Here 1 to 31 are constants days of depend on month. **X H L** are leaves , normal leaves, and normal. I need to check x, h , l values and getting dates.

However, I don't know exactly the logic to check if the values  is the same, then add its value to the same key.

Please help me. Thanking you

Comment: Utilize the purpose of Xcode's Playground :)

Comment: I did't get it. what are you saying. Can you please explain clearly if dont mine.  @Glenn

Comment: Already x,h,l values are there right? Then why you are trying to add values if it is same. What you want to do exactly?

Comment: ^ yea, what do you want to do again? What I was trying to suggest is that you should try Xcode's Playground to actually play and experiment with dictionaries, json, arrays, and other data.

Comment: @ViniApp Yes, X, H, L Values there, by using these values , i want getting dates (keys) ,in which dates having same value. then i will add to calendar. and i am passing month- year to server then he given back with dates and holiday of the month. i felt you understand my Question.

Comment: On another note
Use as? instead of as! - to avoid crashes

Comment: @ViniApp Yes, i Used but i am not getting dates (i.e 1,2,4 etc..) . please help me. and can you pls give me your email id .

Comment: @IosDeveloper What I understand is you need something like this {X : [1,2,3,4], H : [Some dates], L:[Some dates] } ??

Comment: @Jon  Yes, exactly your right. i need same type like as above

Comment: @IosDeveloper What are you getting in `Streams` variable , It is array ? or dictionary ?

Comment: @JonSnow   stream Consol :' { "-" = 3; 1 = X; 10 = H; 11 = X; 12 = X; 13 = X; 14 = X; 15 = X; 16 = X; 17 = H; 18 = X; 19 = X; 2 = X; 20 = X; 21 = X; 22 = X; 23 = L; 24 = H; 25 = X; 26 = L; 27 = X; 28 = "-"; 29 = "-"; 3 = H; 30 = "-"; 4 = X; 5 = X; 6 = X; 7 = X; 8 = X; 9 = X; H = 4; L = 2; X = 21; blank = ""; classid = 1; classname = "(A)"; stdid = 11; stdnm = "Name"; }'

Comment: @IosDeveloper Your data format is wrong !!! , Some where "X" is  as value and somewhere "X" is as KEY , It is not possible to parse

Comment: @JonSnow what  to do now ? can i tell to server remove  the last these key value from  data  'H = 4; L = 2; X = 21 '  ? and There no option to implement it without change format ?

Comment: @IosDeveloper Your data should be in correct format always , YES you need to tell server team to provide correct data , And also you can tell them to provide array of dictionary means [ { } , { } ] it will easy to parse

Answer (score -1):

Please check :

**This is for your JSON Format**

```
if let streams = parsedData["data"] as! [AnyObject]? {
    for stream in streams {
        let dict = stream as? [AnyHashable: Any]
        print(getValue(key: "H", dict: dict!))
        print(getValue(key: "L", dict: dict!))
        print(getValue(key: "X", dict: dict!))
    }
}

func getValue(key: String, dict: [AnyHashable: Any]) -> [Int] {
    return dict.filter { $0.value as? String == key }.flatMap { Int(String(describing: $0.key)) }
}
```

**Below is for dictionaries**

```
let dict = ["-": 4, 1: "X", 10: "H", 11: "X", 12: "X", 13: "X", 14: "X",
           15: "X", 16: "X", 17: "H", 18: "X", 19: "X", 2: "X", 20: "X",
           21: "X", 22: "X", 23: "L", 24: "H", 25: "X", 26: "L", 27: "-",
           28: "-", 29: "-", 3: "H", 30: "-", 4: "X", 5: "X", 6: "X", 7: "X",
           8: "X", 9: "X", "H": 4, "L": 2, "X": 20] as [AnyHashable : Any]
```

**Option 1** Pass the key and will return dates array

```
    print(getValue(key: "H", dict: dict)) //[17, 10, 24, 3]
    print(getValue(key: "L", dict: dict)) //[26, 23]
    print(getValue(key: "X", dict: dict)) //[12, 25, 14, 20, 5, 15, 7, 11, 13, 16, 19, 22, 21, 9, 18, 2, 6, 4, 1, 8]

    func getValue(key: String, dict: [AnyHashable: Any]) -> [Int] {
        return dict.filter { $0.value as? String == key }.flatMap { $0.key as? Int}
    }
```

**Option 2** Pass multiple keys and will return dictionary with dates array associated with each key

```
    print(getValue2(keys: ["H","L","X"], dict: dict))
    //["H": [17, 24, 3, 10], "L": [23, 26], "X": [14, 20, 13, 19, 21, 9, 6, 1, 12, 25, 5, 15, 7, 11, 16, 22, 18, 2, 4, 8]]

    func getValue2(keys: [String], dict: [AnyHashable: Any]) -> [String: [Int]] {
        var returnValue = [String: [Int]]()
        for key in keys {
            returnValue[key] = [Int]()
        }

        dict.forEach {
            if let v = $0.value as? String, returnValue[v] != nil, let k = $0.key as? Int {
                returnValue[v]!.append(k)
            }
        }
        return returnValue
    }
```

Comment: I was getting error:                                                                       let  parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:[]) as! [String:Any] {
 print(parsedData) } .                                                                                                let dict = parsedData["data"] as! [AnyHashable:Any]   ---> error  is Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleObjectArrayI' (0x109f8adb0) to 'NSDictionary'.

Comment: Thanking you. can you please explain as my json. if dont mine. i was stucking with from last 4 days. please help me .

Comment: ha,   for stream in Streams
                 {
                    print(self.getValue(key: "H", dict: stream as! [AnyHashable : Any]))
                    
                        } .     and print is : [ ]

Comment: stream Consol : {
    "-" = 3;
    1 = X;
    10 = H;
    11 = X;
    12 = X;
    13 = X;
    14 = X;
    15 = X;
    16 = X;
    17 = H;
    18 = X;
    19 = X;
    2 = X;
    20 = X;
    21 = X;
    22 = X;
    23 = L;
    24 = H;
    25 = X;
    26 = L;
    27 = X;
    28 = "-";
    29 = "-";
    3 = H;
    30 = "-";
    4 = X;
    5 = X;
    6 = X;
    7 = X;
    8 = X;
    9 = X;
    H = 4;
    L = 2;
    X = 21;
    blank = "";
    classid = 1;
    classname = "(A)";
    stdid = 11;
    stdnm = "Name";
}

Comment: No,I used your updated answer and  Still i am getting null "[ ]", and give me your email id.

Comment: request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
            let task = session4.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)
            {
                data,response,error in
                do { let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:[]) as! [String:Any]
   print(parsedData)
 if parsedData["status"] as! Int == 200 {
  if let streams = parsedData["data"] as! [AnyObject]? {
    for stream in streams {
   if let dict = stream as? [AnyHashable : Any] {
   print(self.getValue(key: "H", dict: stream as! [AnyHashable : Any])) } }}