# Convert array to Segment Title in swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have an Array

```
["Krishna", "Parin"]
```

and I'd like to use it in UISegmentedControl that I created by storyboard.

I Tired with code its working fine when i was taken this type of value

```
  segment.updateTitle(array: [["Ve1"], ["Fa"], ["ven"]])
```

i used below code for implementing:

```
extension UISegmentedControl {

func updateTitle(array titles: [[String]]) {

    removeAllSegments()
    for t in titles {
        let title = t.joined(separator: ", ")
        insertSegment(withTitle: title, at: numberOfSegments, animated: true)
    }

} }
```

Comment: You want to convert your array as per [[String]] or need to change `updateTitle` Method as per your array [String] ?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1) Create new extension that takes array

2) Convert your array

---

Approach One

```
extension UISegmentedControl {

    func updateTitle(array titles: [String]) {
     removeAllSegments()
        for t in titles {
            insertSegment(withTitle: t, at: numberOfSegments, animated: true)
        }

     }
}
```

Pass you array like

```
var array = ["Krishna", "Parin"]

segment.updateTitle(array:array )
```

---

Approach Two

If you don't want to create new  extension

Update your array as per your current extension

```
var arrayOfArray:[[String]] = arrayNames.map{[$0]}
```

Comment: Thank you ! Approach One  Working fine. and One more can you see this question

Comment: @IosDeveloper Glad the solution worked. Would you mind accepting this answer? It might help people
experiencing a similar issue and will help getting your question noticed. For more
information, take a look at our [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Thanks and welcome to SO!

Comment: can you please see this question. [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46440499/how-to-check-same-values-for-the-multiple-keys-in-array-of-json-object/46441755#46441755)

Comment: @IosDeveloper If solution worked then please accept !! By Clicking Right button

Comment: yes, i having less than 15 reputations Mr.Jon. so its not accepting my reputation

Comment: @IosDeveloper  Yes You can, Are you able to see Right button Below 0 in my answer ? , Just press it !!

Comment: How can i pass array of ID into segment as like above. Example:               var array = ["Krishna", "Parin"], Here, Krishna having one ID, and Parin having another ID.   and they are having different data using ID. i need to pass ID to server. when user choose the option name. (segment). how can i resolve it ?